# Does Visual Studio work with TFS 2010 even after I install a compatibility GDR update for TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, tfs

Hi in my company we are upgrading TFS 2010 to TFS 2012.
In order to do that we need to install sp1 and a Compatibility GDR update([from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)) on all of our vs 2010 clients.and a Compatibility GDR update([from here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2673642)) on all of our vs 2008 client.

But We want to do the upgrade in 2 main steps ,first upgrading the client and several days later upgrading the server.

Is the client will be able to work with the tfs 2010 server even after the Compatibility GDR update has been installed?

Any links would be appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I have the GDR update installed on Visual Studio 2010 and it works fine with TFS 2010 and TFS 2012.

If you install the [VersionInfo](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce6cbf1-fb55-4a7d-b39b-8589634d846f) extension for VS2010, it will *nag* you to install the GDR update.

Comment: >Thanks For the answer,

>i found this page very helpful [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788(v=vs.110).aspx#msscci)

>and the specific section:
>>If you connect Team Explorer 2010 to Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server, you can perform the same functions as if you connected an earlier version of Team Explorer to Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server. However, you cannot access new functionality that Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server does not support.